# fileupload not working within gridview inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, asp.net-ajax

i have file upload control in gridview and that gridview is inside update panel
when i try to update gridview everything works but image path from fileupload don't save
please help me...

page.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
                                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="4" 
                                DataKeyNames="pid" ForeColor="Black" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                                GridLines="Horizontal" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                                onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
                                onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                                onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operation">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ForeColor="#94b52c"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" ForeColor="#94b52c"
                                                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete ?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="pid">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblpid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pid") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblproductid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pid") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Detail" SortExpression="pdetail">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtproductdetail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pdetail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblproductdetail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pdetail") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Image" SortExpression="pimage">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgproductimage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("pimage") %>' Height="50px" Width="50px"/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#F0F0F0" ForeColor="Black" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"  />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
                            </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

here is .cs file

```
 public void bindgrid()
{
    string qry = "select pid,pdetail,pimage from productdetail p,categorydetail c where p.cid=c.cid";
    GridView1.DataSource = abal.Qry_Fire(qry);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindgrid();
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label l = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblpid");
    TextBox txtproductdetail = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtproductdetail");
    FileUpload f = (FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("FileUpload1");
    string path = "~/user/product_image/" + f.FileName.ToString();
    int msg = abal.Qry_All("update productdetail set pdetail='" + txtproductdetail.Text + "',pimage='" + path 

+ "' WHERE pid='" + Convert.ToInt32(l.Text) + "'");
    if(msg==1)
        f.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bindgrid();
}
```

Comment: what the error you are facing

Comment: without trigger there is no errror.. but filename of the file is not accessible.. so in **path** field it writes only ~/user/product_image/ but should be ~/user/product_image/filename.jpg

Comment: @merhardik if your answer is solved please update your answer as i am getting an error of Control with ID 'FileUpload1' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `PostBackTrigger` after `</ContentTemplate>` for the `FileUploader`  as below:

```
 </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="FileUpload1" /> 
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Update** if its inside a `gridview` then you can try the below code:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
 {  
   FileUpload flUpload = e.Row.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;  
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(flUpload);  
 }
```

**Update2** add the event `OnRowDataBound` in the `gridview`:

```
<asp:gridview
    id="GridView1" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

rest add your code for `gridview`

Comment: it gives error like "A control with ID 'FileUpload1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdataPanel" 'UpdatePanel1' "   may be reason is FileUpload1 is inside gridview.. can u help plz

Comment: still not working.. with this code there is no change.. rowupdating is also not fire

Comment: I did changes as above. Now it gives following error: Control with ID 'FileUpload1' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler.

Comment: @Arshad if possible can you try to solve this question as it is same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283809/upload-file-not-working-in-updatepanel

Answer (score 3):

I had same kind of problem and fixed it by using below solution.

Add the following code in your code behind.

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

protected void gvLineItems_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {

    if (e.Row.RowState.Equals(DataControlRowState.Edit))
     {
       Button btnUpload = e.Row.FindControl("btnUpload") as Button;
       ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnUpload);
     }
  }
}
```

I am able to retrive the fileUpload control value after adding the above code.

```
protected void UpdateRow(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   FileUpload uploadedFile = (FileUpload)dgDocuments.Rows[editIndex].FindControl("UploadFile");
   if (uploadedFile.HasFile)
   {
    uploadedFile.SaveAs(FileUploadURL + "\\Temp\\" + uploadedFile.FileName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this: Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");  to page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data"); 
             ..............................
         }
```

and Try This.

```
</ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" /> 
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update panel dosen't work properly with some controls similarly with Fileupload..So try to do it with ajax call which is a better option.

Comment: what is the solution ?? can u elaborate it ??

Answer (score 0):

Just Add "Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");" as posted by Jisha Muthuswamy. FileUpload control inside the gridview wrapped by UpdatePanel can never be accessed and thus cannot be set as a PostBackTrigger ControlID. Thanks