# upload file not working in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, updatepanel

***I DONT WANNA GET MY PAGE TO BE GET REFRESH OR POSTBACK***

So I am trying uploading file in updatepanel but onclicking upload button the validation check shows that there is no file

my html code is

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel16" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fp_upload" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btn_browse" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btn_browse_Click" />
   </ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It seems to be

[image]

my .cs code is

```
protected void btn_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (fp_upload.HasFile)
    {
        Response.Write("contains file");
    }
    else
    {
       Response.Write("no file");
    }
}
```

when I used to browse the file and click on upload button every times it goes in else condition. Whats the problem.

***ALSO I DONT WANNA GET MY PAGE TO BE GET REFRESH OR POSTBACK***

Answer (score 3):

To use a FileUpload control inside an UpdatePanel control, set the postback control that submits the file to be a PostBackTrigger control for the panel.

Comment: i dont wanna page to be refresh

Comment: Well then ... you should use AsyncFileUpload control instead

Comment: will surely try and let u know

Comment: on putting it in update panel, asyncfileupload is getting refreshed

Comment: I think so using asyncfileupload is a bad option

Comment: Did you try it using UpdateMode="Conditional" on the update panel. Also, I wouldn't call it a bad option because it should do exactly what you are looking to do.

Comment: in asyncfileuploa or in normal upload

Answer (score 1):

just add `PostBackTrigger` after `</ContentTemplate>` for the `FileUploader` as below:

```
 </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="FileUpload1" /> 
     </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and add the below code in page load :

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(FileUpload1);
```

or if you want to make it async, you can use [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-FileUpload-Control-inside-ASP.Net-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Control.aspx) :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAsyncUpload" runat="server"
           Text="Async_Upload" OnClick = "Async_Upload_File" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"
           OnClick = "Upload_File" />               
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnAsyncUpload"
          EventName = "Click" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnUpload" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: on using 1st step i m facing error as Control with ID 'fp_upload' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler.

Comment: using 2nd step what shall i have to write in OnClick = "Async_Upload_File" and OnClick = "Upload_File"

Comment: please make this answer some what to my question

Comment: Actually i have already tried this code as you have made this code for gridview in that post but same error is coming

Comment: Actually my code is working on doing    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnUpload" />, but here the page get refresh that i dont want..

Comment: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/aspnet/R8SX290512-Asp.Net-asynchronous-file-upload-using-jquery.html

Comment: you can use async with jquery

Comment: it also refreshes the page, i had a good talk about this with @Moe S.

Comment: The link you provided is good but it will not help in saving image or any other file to my application , it will just show image name and size

Answer (score 0):

Write **trigger** will instruct the button that we are using for the upload to perform a full postback

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel16" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_browse" />
       </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fp_upload" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btn_browse" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btn_browse_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>  
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: but i dont wanna page to be refresh or get postback