# How to edit/update in dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have dynamic `DataTable` says to be `DataTable dt=New DataTable();` and column name says to be **ID**, **F_name**, **L_name**.
I had fill a value to this column seems to be

```
ID     |    F_name   |    L_name
 1     |     mit     |    jain
 2     |     raj     |    patel
 3     |     anki    |    patel
 4     |     alpa    |    dumadiya
```

If I want to edit/update column `2` says to be `ID=2`, `F_name` that is `raj` to `rajan`

what shall I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = GetTable();

    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("ID=2 and F_Name='raj'");
    if (dr !=null)
    {
        foreach (var item in dr)
        {
            item["F_name"] = "rajan";
        }
    }

}

static DataTable GetTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("F_name");
    dt.Columns.Add("L_name");

    dt.Rows.Add("1", "mit", "jain");          
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "raj", "patel");
    dt.Rows.Add("3", "anki", "patel");
    dt.Rows.Add("4", "alpa", "dumadiya");

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: thanks its working...can you try to solve this question as it is same on uploadfile...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283809/upload-file-not-working-in-updatepanel